# get checkbox Controls by custom attribute name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a collection of checkbox some 40-50 nos and i have set a attribute 'attr-ID' for each checkbox which is a unique value ID in database. how can i get the control by attribute name in c# code. I want to check some of the checkbox according to dB values on page load event.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="rdCervical" attr-ID='111' runat='server' />
```

Comment: Do they have runat="server" attribute or are they simple html elements?

Comment: HTML5 allows attributes that begin with `data-` but for anything else I think you'll have to write your own parser, I'm afraid.

Comment: yea they have runat server but i cannot identifiy the control id in c#

Comment: If they have runat="=server" they should be available in the code behind. are they located maybe in a custom control? Can you post some more code of the containers?

Comment: its a normal html control but i have many checkbox and identifying each checkbox id in server side have to check each id and the attribute value which i dont need. so if there some way to check the attribute and get it checked.

Comment: @deepu Just happened upon this question, what answer did you go with?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = FindControlByAttribute<HtmlInputCheckBox>(this.Page, "attr-ID", "111");

}
public T FindControlByAttribute<T>(Control ctl, string attributeName, string attributeValue) where T : HtmlControl
{
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(T) && ((T)c).Attributes[attributeName]==attributeValue)
        {
            return (T) c;
        }
        var cb= FindControlByAttribute<T>(c, attributeName, attributeValue);
        if (cb != null)
            return cb;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: He is not using server controls, but html controls `HtmlInputCheckBox`

Comment: @Arion : can u specify a region in your function means to find a control in a specified div like i have some 50 checkbox in a div which have a id ='dvCheckboxes'. i used your funciton but i am always getting null value. thanks for your post.. and pls help

Comment: @deepu: this function loops all the control on the page. If there is a control with the attribute attr-ID and the value of that is 111 the it will return it. If you have a div with checkboxes see so that it has runat="server". Then you can use that control in this function and it will return the checkbox

Answer (score 5):

```
if (rdCervical.Attributes["attr-ID"] != null)
{
      string id = rdCervical.Attributes["attr-ID"];
      rdCervical.Checked = true;
}
```

I assume you are adding the checkboxes programatically. In that case, make a container `<div id="checkContainer" runat="server"></div>` and put all your checkboxes inside it. Then just use `checkContainer.InnerHtml` and parse that code with [this library](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). You can then easily use the library API to find elements by attribute, I think the method was `SelectNodes`

Without this library, there is no easy way to navigate through HTML elements from code.

Comment: the checkbox id cannot be checked since i have many checkboxes i have a common attribute for all checkbox using it i need to identify which checkbox is need to be checked

Comment: I assume you are adding the checkboxes programatically. In that case, make a container `<div id="checkContainer" runat="server"></div>` and put all your checkboxes inside it. Then just use `checkContainer.InnerHtml` and parse that code with this library. You can then easily use the library API to find elements by attribute. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/