# asp.net: append a div after a div in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to append a div (with is content), after all tags with a specific css class (or data- tag) in code behind of asp.net c#.

Someone can help me? Basically it should work as "append" in jquery. I searched online but could not find anything, especially to "append" to a tag with a specific CSS class.

Thank you.

Comment: If you say `div` and `codebehind` use a `Panel`. Apart from that, use `parent.Controls.Add(panel)` where `parent` is the container control (f.e. another `Panel`) that contains your controls.

Comment: Thanks, is possibile with panel to append a div to all tag with a specific css class?

Comment: So you have a panel and you want to append it behind every other control with a given css class? Note that this works only with server controls anyway. So you can access a `div` from codebehind if it's `runat=server` but you cannot access (or append a control behind) a control like `input type=text` that is not `runat=server`. Why do you need such an unusual requirement?

Comment: imagine I have many article on a page: `<h1>title</h1><div class='description'>text</div>`, I need to append dynamically a div with a link after the div with class 'description': `<h1>title</h1><div class='description'>text</div><div>link</div>`. This is because it works on all div with 'description' css class without worrying about create the html page in a certain way. I can do it with Jquery, but running in asp.net is more compatible and simple to integrate with other code behind.

Comment: @RobAnd take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8605204/961695

Comment: yes, could be. I depth on it, otherwise will use jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a diva as an html generic control from the code behind

for example i have a div like this

```
<div id="test" runat="server">Some Content</div>
```

As i specified runat server it will be available there and i can add contents like this

```
HtmlGenericControl div= HtmlGenericControl();
div.TagName = "div"; //specify the tag here
//then specify the attributes
div.Attributes["height"] = "100%";
div.Attributes["width"] = "100%";
div.Attributes["class"] = "someclass";
div.Attributes["id"] = "someid";
test.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main focus is I have n tags with class="myclass" and I need to append a div to all tag with this css class. With jquery is simple, but in c# I was not able.

Comment: Let me see if we can iterate the same logic for multiple elements